# Set pandas.series.between() value to a variable

Tags: pandas

I am trying to plot only a specific data range, and have pandas export those data points as a .txt file. In order to only manually enter the data bounds once, I was hoping I could use a variable to define the data range, and have pd.between() read that data range.

For example:

```
Lz1 = (2.25, 3)

L1.set_xlim(Lz1)

L1_txt = df[df['Time'].between(Lz1)]
```

As the function is looking for a left and a right bound, I get the following error when I run my code:

TypeError: between() missing 1 required positional argument: 'right'

Is there a way to have the function use a single variable? Thank you!

Comment: df[df['Time'].between(2.25, 3)]

Comment: You can do `between(*Lz1)`,  The splat `*` expands a list or tuple into a set of arguments.

Comment: @hrokr No need to take [python] off of the tag list - all pandas questions are also python questions.

Comment: @NickODell - meaning the python part, which this doesn't reference, is redundant.

Comment: @hrokr The question may not reference Python, but it's certainly useful in answering the question - how would you know to use the `*` operator except with a Python background? And the vast majority of [tag:pandas] questions are also tagged with python, so I don't think the community feels the tag is redundant.

Comment: @NickODell No, you apply the tags that fit. Often with pandas that's python. But not always. I mean, why not add in matplotlib? It doesn't really fit either but pandas uses the same API so, but using your logic, you should.